# How can I check if I've received all of the data using Net

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a chunk of code that receives data every 5-10 seconds and parses that data. The problem is that the `socket.on('data' function...` doesn't get all of the data before moving on. I am using Net.

Code example:

```
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  console.log('CONNECTION: ' + socket.remoteAddress +':'+ socket.remotePort);
  socket.setEncoding('utf8');

  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    handleDataObjects(JSON.parse(data));
  });

}).listen(PORT);
```

I also tried something I saw online that is this:

```
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
console.log('CONNECTION: ' + socket.remoteAddress +':'+ socket.remotePort);
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
totalData = "";
socket.on('data', function (data) {
    totalData += data;
});
socket.on('end', function(){
    handleDataObjects(JSON.parse(totalData));
    socket.end();
})
}).listen(PORT);
```

However I never get into the `socket.on('end')` because that's only when the socket is closed says the documentation so I'm not sure why people are suggesting that on here.

Comment: `socket.on('data')` can be called multiple times.  You need to collect the data across those events, and then trigger your action on `socket.on('end', ...)`

Comment: @joe in my second example isn't that what's going on? I build all of the data, but how do i get it to socket.end?

Comment: If your connection stays open, then you will have to determine in your `.on('data')` calls when you have enough data to process.  However, `'end'`) should get called at the completion of each client connection.

Comment: Also, you should not have to call `socket.end()` in your 2nd example.

Comment: @joe Well the client stays connected and will send data every few seconds. Would it be better to open a new connection each time to send data or keep the connection open?

Comment: Not necessarily.  But if your data comes in in chunks, how do you tell you have a complete "message" to process?  You'll have to do that in your data handler.

Comment: @joe well what happens is I have a client that listens on a file, and when that file changes it sends the new data over to the server. Sometimes the data is too large to send in one chunk(or at least the server receives it in multiple chunks). I might be best using some character to denote the end of a data stream.

Comment: Two things 1: why does not client end connection if it has passed all the data like you expect. 2: It seems like you are using sockets for streaming data. If it is continuous unending stream, then parse on end strategy would not work. It is how http is handled, but socket is low-level. You would have to use some metadata to recognize data start/end. Client must also have to talk in this language.